# List of model inside main model

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have a Main Model with list of other model.
    Ex.:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public string number;

    List<ListViewModel> list {get; set;}
}

public class ListViewModel
{
    public string name;

    public string GenderID;
    public SelectList Gender;
}
```

I want to show my MainModel with list, like:

```
Field Number: Number
List:

name  | Gender
NameA | DropdownList with options and selected item.
NameB | DropdownList with options and selected item.
```

My problem is binding value on dropdownlist of values. for example I want to show nameA with Gender Fem of options Fem/Max/Other.

Comment: Are you looking for help with your view?

Comment: yes Richard Everett

Answer (score 0):

When using `XAML`:

- First of all the you have to create properties for `name`, `GenderID` and `Gender` instead of fields.
- Set the `MainViewModel` as the `DataContext` of your view
- Set the `list` as `ItemSource` for the `DropdownList` (remember the `list` should be public)
- Create a template for the items of the `DropDownList`